# What are the exposed REST api in Discussion board?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, discussion-board

I am trying to utilize REST api to get/set discussion list fields. I am facing issue for following fields,

I am able to set below fields using CSOM but I want to set it using REST api because I am planning to utilize outside of SharePoint.

Best Reply: BestAnswerId

Mark as Featured: IsFeatured

Enterprise keywords/tags

**Update:** below is my data. when I call api using below data, Title gets updated but not BestAnwserId.

```
var itemProperties = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.Community_x0020_DiscussionListItem" },
    'BestAnswerId':64,
    'Title':"updatedd"      
       
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The BestAnswerId and the IsFeatured are properties on the original post, so a GET request on the original post itself will show true/false if that post was featured, same with BestAnswerId by showing the item ID that was marked as best reply.

You can view the result with a request such as:

```
https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('discussionboard')/items/getbyid(1)
```

Where 1 is the ID for the original post.

Note, for the enterprise keywords, you will need to enable it on the list itself first, so the column gets created. After it will be available through the TaxKeyword field.

Comment: Yes I can get BestAnswerId and IsFeatured fields but while setting it doest work. for other fields it works.

Answer (score 0):

All the property for fields in Rest API can be got from Item endpoint:

/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items

[image]

Comment: Yes I can get BestAnswerId and IsFeatured fields but while setting it doest work. for other fields it works

Comment: @AnilPal, the BestAnswerId should be int value rather than a string value, please set like this:
'BestAnswerId': 64

Comment: tried passing int value but still doesn't work. I don't know why this is happening while same way CSOM works.

Comment: Seems this is because "ReadOnlyField" property for BestAnswerId column is set to true, please check with this endpoint: /_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('ListName')/fields/getbyTitle('Best Response Id'), this property can't be updated via Rest I have tested like this :

https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/set-list-column-read-only-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api

I think this is causing the issue. But csom code is working actually.

Comment: I guess, "ReadOnlyField" cannot not be true. Otherwise CSOM code will also not work. May be It is not exposed in REST API. what you say?

Comment: Yes, should be false in my mind, but when I check with this endpoint: it's returning true.

 /_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('ListName')/fields/getbyTitle('Best Response Id')